# How to receive notifications in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been looking around the internet but didn't find what i'm looking for, so i am going to try and see if someone can help me here.

In our company's system, there is a page that users can write comments on, and we wanted to add a feature where we recieve notifications when a user writes a comment. Something similar to facebook's notification feature. Are there any packages that can help with that? As .net core doesn't seem to have something similar.

Comment: The `Asp.Net Core` MVC templates have email and sms messaging built in, at least they used to. You can probably look at one of those and modify to your needs.

Comment: You can use SignalR for this purpose